# Changing the entire layout with orientation change, android

Tags: android, performance

I've set two layout files for a given a fragment (one for portrait, one for landscape). The landscape layout consist of only a `SimpleExoPlayer` view while the portrait layout consist of a `recyclerview` containing different types of elements. What I want is to lock the orientation to portrait mode unless there is a specific type of element (view holder) shown on the screen, only then landscape is possible. What I don't know is what is best (theoretically). **Can I have two totally different layouts that are swapped out when device orientation changes? Should I have both layouts in the same file and change the visibility upon screen rotation? Should I use a `FragmentTransaction`to switch back and forth between layouts?**

disabling/enabling orientation changes seemed simple. The `Recyclerview.ViewHolder`objects in my `recyclerview` are also `LifeCyclerOwners`, I use a `MutableLiveData` object to communicate directly with the activity (the activity knows how many of the specified type of `ViewHolder` are shown at any given time). The `ViewHolder` can pass the video url (and other relevant data) to the fragment, such that upon screen rotation the fragment can be responsible for preparing/playing the video from where it left off in the `recyclerview`.

Answer (score 1):

put the xml under res> layout-land

Answer (score 1):

Create two different XML files, one for design in portrait mode and other for landscape mode. Put in layout-port and layout-land folder inside res folder.

Example:

`res/layout-port [Portrait Mode; default]
main.xml`

`res/layout-land [Landscape Mode]
main1.xml`

**Reference Documentation**: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html

Comment: here's the thing, I also use the databinding library, when I created the second layout (for landscape mode) I could not get a reference to the `SimpleExoPlayerView` so I ended up just adding it to the main layout with the intention of toggling the visibility.

Comment: Why can't you reference to `SimpleExoPlayerView`? The XML layout are technically the same, just altered in their orientation. Add the relevant code as an edit in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use constraint layout: It provides a layout resource for each orientation and resolution you want to support.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent
        android:layout_height="match_content"/>
```

You don't need to create dimensions for different layout sizes and resolutions.